# display null rows in my sql using joins

Tags: mysql

with the help of the below query i was able to fetch 15 rows only but the actual rows are 16
one row is null

so how can i fetch that row also total i should get 16 rows please help me....

```
select p.partnerid,p.name,count(*) as accounts,sum(c.amount) as amount,sum(c.netamt) as netamt,
sum(c.netamt - c.amount) as interest,
sum(case when c.installment = 20 then c.amount else 0 end) as Twenty,
sum(case when c.installment = 10 then c.amount else 0 end) as Ten,
sum(case when c.installment = 5 then c.amount else 0 end) as Five,
sum(case when c.installment = 2 then c.amount else 0 end) as Two
from partnerinfo p left outer join customerinfo c on p.partnerid = c.partnerid
where c.startdate >= '2011-3-15' and c.startdate <= '2012-12-30' and p.manager=1 group by p.partnerid
```

Even if i change the date from 2011-3-15 as 2012-3-15 empty rows should show.
I tried my level best but unable to achieve it.

Please help me.....

Comment: how are you fetching this data? mysql won't create an all-null row in a left-join situation.

Comment: we didnt had any rows in the customerinfo table. when there are no rows i need to display null rows

Comment: Do you have two entries with the same partner ID in the partnerinfo table?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select p.partnerid,p.name,count(*) as accounts,sum(c.amount) as amount,sum(c.netamt) as netamt,
sum(c.netamt - c.amount) as interest,
sum(case when c.installment = 20 then c.amount else 0 end) as Twenty,
sum(case when c.installment = 10 then c.amount else 0 end) as Ten,
sum(case when c.installment = 5 then c.amount else 0 end) as Five,
sum(case when c.installment = 2 then c.amount else 0 end) as Two
from partnerinfo p left outer join customerinfo c on p.partnerid = c.partnerid
where (c.startdate is null OR (c.startdate >= '2011-3-15' and c.startdate <= '2012-12-30')) 
and (p.manager is null OR p.manager=1)
group by p.partnerid
```

Comment: Hi somnath with the help of ur reply i was able to get only if the manager is null but if i had partner is null, they are not displaying. please help me.

Comment: Do you mean partnerinfo can also have NULL? Which column can be NULL or is it that the whole row may not exist?

Comment: the whole row may not exist, and at particular time all the columns will be present but it should be displayed as null when date was changed.

Comment: hi here i am fetching only when the whole row does not exist. when i change the date as shown below                                   "where (c.startdate is null OR (c.startdate >= '2011-3-15'..)"  TO    "where (c.startdate is null OR (c.startdate >= '2012-3-15'..)" it is not showing null rows. This is the problem i had.

Comment: Hi please see this images for better images http://i46.tinypic.com/155l4cp.jpg,
 
http://i49.tinypic.com/357ki3b.jpg